# MySQL select statment when comparing two columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql

You helped a lot with my previous problem a few days ago so i thought I'd ask for help with my current issue.

I have a table named `orders` with `quote` and `payment` fields

I'm trying to get it to display all the data where `quote=payment` so i did the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE quote = '$payment'
```

However, it doesn't work, but if i do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE quote = '10'
```

Then it works perfectly, any ideas why it doesn't seem to want to work when comparing two columns, but works when I add the number directly into the query? Both columns are `int` as well. Thanks for any help.

Comment: How are you assigning value to $payment?

Comment: May be your quote field is not int type..check your db

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE quote = payment"`

Comment: Assign the select to a variable and echo it, what is the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correct you are trying to find rows where the values in the `quote` and `payment` columns match. If so, you just need to compare the column names (in other words, I'm not sure where the `$payment` variable is coming into play here. Maybe the `$` is just a typo out of habit?).

```
"SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE quote = payment"
```

Comment: Yep. That is what I made out of his post too that he wants to compare values of two the columns

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to compare two columns from the same table, you should rather do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 = column2
```

Answer (score 0):

Number comparison in mysql do not need this -> '

so instead of

```
"SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE quote = '$payment'"
```

try

```
"SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE quote = $payment"
```